# Fedora Core 6 Migration

Tags: linux, php, fedora, update

I am at a loss as to what I should to for this server. I need it to run php5.3 and corresponding version of mysql.

I received a client today through work that is using Fedora core 6 running 10 very small websites on some very hodge podge setup. My original idea was just upgrade to php5.3. I have yum (installed 3.0.8) reconfigured for the fedora archive. The latest version of php it allows is 5.1.8. I am still relatively new to server setups and am nervous about wiping their server to upgrade it. Since it is about 6-8 years old I'm not sure if it will even support the newest version of fedora.

The server specs are:

```
Parallels Plesk Panel version   9.5.4
Operating system    Linux 2.6.9-023stab048.4-smp
CPU GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Xeon(R)CPU E5335 @ 2.00GHz
(10gb disk space and 1gb of memory).
```

I use fedora for my personal server so I was a little familiar with it. I haven't done anything too extravagant. Is there a way I can escape this nightmare with installing php5.3 or do I need to migrate these sites to a new server?

Comment: Rebuild it from scratch on a modern operating system that will be supported for more than 13 months.

Comment: This is why you don't run Fedora (a desktop OS) on a server. Support ends quickly for it and development jumps to the next version. You should strongly persuade them to move to something like CentOS.

Comment: Another thing you need to be concerned about is Plesk. In my past work experience with Plesk, it was not friendly to performing upgrades outside the Plesk app and caused some issues. I'd get a VPS for their site (at least temporarily) or migrate your existing data & sites to a new machine with a server-grade OS and bring their site over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora Core 6 makes up RHEL5 (at least according to wikipedia). You can try adding repository [IUS Community](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/About.html) which provides latest php for RHEL which hopefully compatible with Fedora (RHEL5 in your case).

As for whether it'll be supported on newer OS or not, I believe it should be supported. Linux rarely breaks compatibility of older hardware (assuming you're not using a binary-only driver).

Though if I read kernel, ram, and cpu correctly, it looks like an OpenVZ (or similar) instance, not a real machine.